# Do we have the same characterization of $(H^1(\Omega))^*$ as that of $(H^1_0(\Omega))^*$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is the characterization theorem for $H^{-1}(U):=(H_0^1)^*(U)$in Evans's Partial Differential Equations:

[image]

Here is my **question**:

> If one defines $H^{-1}(U)$ as the dual of $H^1(U)$ instead, is the theorem above still true?

---

Here

- $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
- $H^{1}(U)$ is the Sobolev space of $L^{2}(U)$ functions with weak derivatives in $L^{2}(U)$
- $H_{0}^{1}(U)$ is the closure of the subspace $\mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}(U)$ of compactly supported smooth functions on $U$
- $H^{-1}(U)$ is the (continuous) dual of $H_{0}^{1}(U)$

Comment: you  might want to mention which Sobolev spaces the H's refer to, in case Evans's notation is not standard or not everyone who knows the material is familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

The only characterization you can say:
$$ (H^1(\Omega))^{*} = H^{-1}_{\overline{\Omega}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
where
 $$H^{-1}_{\overline{\Omega}}(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{ u\in H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)\,:\, Sppt\, u \subseteq \overline{\Omega}\}.$$

For more details, I recommend you to go through this book

Strongly Elliptic Systems and Boundary Integral Equations : William McLean.